# Sum of two representations of algebras: explaining a note by Jacobson

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

$L$ be a Lie algebra over field $F$, and $M$ a module over $F$ on which $L$ acts in two ways: 
$$\rho_1:L\rightarrow {\rm End }(M), \,\,\,\,\rho_2:L\rightarrow {\rm End }(M).$$
This means precisely, for each $x\in L$, $\rho_i(x)$ is $F$-linear map from $M$ to $M$ and for all $x,y\in L$,
$$\rho_i([x,y])=[\rho_i(x),\rho_i(y)].$$

**Proposition.** *Suppose that $[\rho_1(x),\rho_2(y)]=0$ for all $x,y\in L$. Then 
$$\rho:L\rightarrow {\rm End}(M), \,\,\,\, \rho(x)=\rho_1(x)+\rho_2(x)$$
is a Lie algebra representation of $L$.*

**Proof.** See Jacobson's Lie algebra, p. 20.

After this work, Jacobson writes the following.

> *Note.* Nothing like this holds in the associative case.

**Question.** Can one explain a little bit this Note? He want to say that if $L$ is replced by associative algebra (not Lie) and we consider its two representations (with action on same vector space), can't we define sum, with extra assumption that the images of two representations commute with each other?

Comment: Just a remark - you have changed Jacobson's text.  A representation is *not* "over the module $M$". Rather $M$ becomes a Lie algebra module via $\rho$. The Lie bracket $[\rho(x),\rho(y)]$ is the one for the Lie algebra ${\rm End}(V)$ over a vector space $V$. Then $x.v=\rho(x)v$ identifies "module" and "representation" of $L$. Of course the conclusion after $(26)$ in Jacobson's text  does not hold for associative algebra representations. Just try with $A=M_n(K)$ and representations of it as associative algebra.

Comment: I changed it, and hope that the changed text is now correct. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: very good (+1)...

Comment: If a representation of a unital associative algebra has to take $1$ in the algebra to $\mathrm{id}_V$ on the vector space $V$, then the sum of two representations cannot be a representation, since $1$ in the algebra would map to $2\mathrm{id}_V$. There is probably a similar argument even when this hypothesis is relaxed, since there is only one way to add a unit into an associative algebra.